# VS2019 and Github : 'ensure-core-worktree' is not a valid submodule--helper subcommand

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, clone, visual-studio-2019

From VS2019, I try to get: https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy.git

Receveived:

Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
'ensure-core-worktree' is not a valid submodule--helper subcommand

Why?

=========================================================================================
Also as additional information:

Action: Start cloning...

...
Remote: Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.
Remote: Total 100061 (delta 40), reused 32 (delta 23), pack-reused 99959
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 7: **basename**: command not found
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 7: **sed**: command not found
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 19: .: **git-sh-setup**: file not found
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: CloneCommand.ExecuteClone

**Solution:**

Added PATHs with all bin folder of Git. ie: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin, ... plus all other Git bin folders, if any.

Action: Start cloning...

...
Remote: Total 100061 (delta 40), reused 32 (delta 23), pack-reused 99959
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 19: .: git-sh-setup: file not found
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: CloneCommand.ExecuteClone

**Solution:**

Too old version of Git. I Installed version 2.17.1 for testing purpose but you better should install latest.

Action: Start cloning...

...
Remote: Total 100061 (delta 40), reused 32 (delta 23), pack-reused 99959
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 7: basename: command not found
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 7: sed: command not found
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 19: .: git-sh-setup: file not found
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: CloneCommand.ExecuteClone

**Solution:**

Added PATH:
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin

Action: Start cloning...

...
Remote: Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.
Remote: Total 100061 (delta 40), reused 32 (delta 23), pack-reused 99959
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 19: .: git-sh-setup: file not found
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: CloneCommand.ExecuteClone

**Solution:**

Added PATH: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core

Start cloning...

...
Remote: Total 798 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 795
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
**'ensure-core-worktree' is not a valid submodule--helper subcommand**

?????

**Solution:**

> I uninstalled: 2.17.1 and installed lastest (2019-12-03): 2.24.0.2  (Select Adjusting PATH to "Use Git and optional Unix tools...")

The repository was cloned succesfully !!!! ... Finally!!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ensure-core-worktree" is a subcommand of submodule--helper.
It is present only in version 2.20 of git and above.

https://lwn.net/Articles/774686/